# Toggling visibility of segmentation fault messsages in dmesg

Tags: logs, dmesg, segmentation-fault

When applications segfault, I generally see messages like this in `dmesg`:

```
pstree[25678]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f58be0b3ae4 sp 00007ffe65b700a0 error 4 in libc-2.24.so[7f58be04d000+195000]
```

However, I think somehow I must have changed my kernel settings somewhere, because I no longer see these messages in `dmesg`. I am triggering segfaults with this C program:

```
#include <signal.h>

int main()
{
        raise(SIGSEGV);
}
```

I know my loglevel is set at [`KERN_DEBUG`](https://elinux.org/Debugging_by_printing):

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/printk
7   4   1   7
```

and I know I can see output in `dmesg` like this:

```
sudo sh -c "printf '<%s> Log level %s (KERN_DEBUG)\n' '7' '7' > /dev/kmsg"
```

and I know `debug.exception-trace` is set to 1:

```
$ sysctl debug.exception-trace 
debug.exception-trace = 1
$ cat /proc/sys/debug/exception-trace 
1
```

but I still don't get segfault notifications. The [`dmesg` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dmesg.1.html) talks about coloring segfault messages, but not about turning them on or off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A segmentation fault is not the same thing as a SIGSEGV signal. A signal is just a signal. When you have an actual segmentation fault, that is when the kernel will log it, and subsequently send a SIGSEGV signal to your application.

The logic behind this, and why the kernel only logs on a real segmentation fault, is that the kernel (and CPU) is what enforces the rules about what address space your program has and is allowed to access. Thus when those rules are broken, it is the one to log the action.

To properly test, you need to actually do something in your code that will generate a segmentation fault, such as accessing an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: Interesting! Do you have an example program to reliably trigger a segfault? I was going off this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045314/why-cant-i-cause-a-seg-fault

Comment: The question itself in that link is not a good way to trigger a segfault no. However several of the answers are. `*(char *)0 = 0;` should work fine. Yes it is theoretically possible that this might not segfault, but unless you're on some esoteric system, it should work fine. And since I doubt you're releasing production code which deliberately segfaults, I don't think portability is a concern.